# can i send function output data to mail?

Tags: php

I have 2 functions and I want to send all functions data to my mail
I tried like this 
these are my functions

```
function cart1();
function cart2();
```

my function codes

```
<?php
function cart1  () {
    foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value){
        if ($value>0) {
            if (substr($name, 0, 5)=='cart_') {
                $id = substr($name, 5, (strlen($name)-5));
                $get = mysql_query('SELECT id, name, price FROM products WHERE id='.mysql_real_escape_string((int)$id));
                while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {
                    $sub = $get_row['price']*$value;
                    echo $get_row['name'].' x '.$value.' @ &pound;'.number_format($get_row['price'], 2).' = &pound;'.number_format($sub, 2).'<a href="cart.php?remove='.$id.'">[-]</a> <a href="cart.php?add='.$id.'">[+]</a> <a href="cart.php?delete='.$id.'">[Delete]</a><br />';
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
?>

<form action="email.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cart1" value="<?php cart1 (); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="cart2" value="<?php cart2 (); ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

I just want to know how to convert function's output into form object. can any 1 help me.

Comment: What is wrong with what you have there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
     function cart1() {
          $results = '';
          foreach(...) {
               ...
               $results .= $get_row['name'].' x '.$value.' @ &pound;'.number_format($get_row['price'], 2).' = &pound;'.number_format($sub, 2).'<a href="cart.php?remove='.$id.'">[-]</a> <a href="cart.php?add='.$id.'">[+]</a> <a href="cart.php?delete='.$id.'">[Delete]</a><br />';
          }
          return $results;
     }
?>



<input type="hidden" name="cart1" value="<?php echo cart1 (); ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="cart2" value="<?php echo cart2 (); ?>">
```

Comment: thanks again but having same problem its show the result also in form which i dont want to show the visitor. i set the type hidden but its showing the function result i cant understand. i think value cant be the function.

Comment: can you explain your problem a little more pls?

Comment: why do you have to send the data with a form? can't you just run the function cart1() in email.php? all your data is in the session or database, no client side storage needed.

Comment: thanks for ur great help. actually i am trying to learn php i never tought about include my cart function in my email scripts. i will try this. thankssssss